# Change in inputTextArea not sent to controller - within jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: apex, visualforce

I've seen a few posts but I haven't found any solutions.  Hopefully you can help.

I have an apex:InputTextArea pointed to a controller variable.  I only get a result of Null.  It isn't saving the value :(  Help!

** UPDATE: found out WHAT is causing it to mess up.. it's the  tags.  If I take them out, it works.  Issue is, I NEED it to be in a dialog... anyone? **

VF PAGE - it's about 1600 lines, pretty complex piece, but I'll simplify it as I can.  (moving Script tags to the bottom of page doesn't affect anything)

```
    <apex page>



     <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'jquery.min.js')}"/> 
     <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'jquery-ui.min.js')}"/> 
     <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'jquery.tablesorter.min.js')}"/> 
     <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'jquery-ui.min.css')}"/>  
     <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'jquery-ui.css')}"/> 
     <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.tablesorter, 'theme.green.css')}"/>



       <script type="text/javascript">  
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function () {
        init();
        sortTable();
    });

function init(){
    j$("#otherDialog").dialog({resizeable: false, modal: true, autoOpen:false,
         });
    }
function otherOpener(){
        j$("#otherDialog").dialog( "open" );
        }
    function otherCloser(){
        j$("#otherDialog").dialog( "close" );
        }
</script>


       <apex form>


          <apex:pageblock>
            <apex:pageblocksection/>
            <apex:pageblocksection/>
           <apex:pageblocksection/>
          </apex:pageblock>
                <div id = "Otherdialog" title ="title">
                    <apex:pageblock id="dialogId">
                        <apex:outputtext value="Please enter value"/>
                        <apex:inputtextarea id="inputTextArea" value="{!value}" />
                        <apex:commandButton value="Save & Close" action="{!updateValue}"
                                            status="PleaseWait" rerender="false" 
                                            oncomplete="otherCloser();" immediate="false"/>
                    </apex:pageblock>        
                </div>
         </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

My Controller.

```
public string value {get;set;}
```

If I set a value of "blah" in the controller, it keeps that value.  It seems that when I click the command Button, it does not pass the InputTextArea content to the {!value} variable.  I took out the "on complete" from the button, incase the JS was completing before the DOM, but no change.

Help please!

edit: changing this to a apex:InputText, Input, etc has no effect

Comment: Can you post the entire markup?

Comment: update is a reserved keyword you cannot name your method as update, were you able to save your class?

Comment: Well, I edited the code a bit to take out some details, so it's not actually called update, its called 
"{!updatesomethingsomething}" - good catch though!

Comment: @BrianMansfield sure thing.

Comment: why are you using rerender="false" if you do not want to refresh the whole page try rerendering specific components and where are you checking the value of the value variable, inside or before the updatevalue method in the controller

Comment: Since the command button is in a pop up dialog, rerendering the form or another component will leave it open.  So I just put it to false so it doesn't rerender anything.  I tried it pointing to other things instead of "false" and no effect.         I am checking the value of the variable inside the updatevalue method of the controller.

Comment: Fun Fact: OK, so, if I put that Div inside of a of a pageblock section, it DOES save the value.  Only issue is that it displays the apex components in the pageblocksection and not the dialog.  But that's one step closer - trying to use html components instead.

Comment: I used your exact code, minus the action functions, status etc in my dev org . The value of inputtext is passed without any issue to the controller. Should be something to do wth action functions

Comment: Found out what it was!  You were right.  It's the DIV tags.  I take them out, works like magic.  Problem is, I NEED the div tags to make them a jquery Dialog.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

@Rao was Correct - in that the code by itself WORKS.

HOWEVER... I am using a jQuery UI DIALOG.  This is important.

**Take a look at #3 here:  [Gotchas Using jQueryUI](http://improveit360.blogspot.ca/2010/09/gotchas-using-jqueryui-to-make-popups.html)**

Basically, it pops the dialog to BENEATH the form.  fix in the link.